# Do we model stock prices using non-Markovian processes in continuous setting?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, modeling, models

In a continuous setting, is it common to model stock prices using non-Markovian processes ? If so, do you have some examples of models ? Or is Markovianity something "embedded" in the continuous setting ? There is a lot of literature on diffusions processes, but what about non-Markovian financial models ? Any books/articles to recommend ?

Sorry if this is a basic question, I am mathematician learning finance on my own.

Comment: This is not often done (if ever) to my knowledge.  Consider that when Heath Jarrow Morton  developed a non Markovian model of *interest rates*, this was seen as a disadvantage and reduced the popularity of the model. Quants like to keep things mathematically simple, maybe because we don't know enough math. Non Markovian models are difficult to work with theoretically and computationally.

Comment: But surely, stock prices cannot be Markov...There is often deep path dependence, that we can model using statistics/ML. Aren't quants bothered by that ?

Comment: Technical analysis could be viewed as non-markovian because technicians use the past heavily. Similarly for any ARIMA type time series model. So, I would say that non-markov models are used but mostly  in very simple ways.

Comment: So in your opinion, there is no "canonical" (just like exponential BM is canonical for diffusions) path dependent model for stock prices in continuous time ?